# SQL - Query MAX on integer column and date specific

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, max

I am working on a report query where I need only the highest most recent row using a date range, as well as patientid, and Type_Name . The int column 'ednum' can have many rows on any particular date, i just need the row with the highest ednum for that patient in the date range.

I am using a single table attempting to drill down to show one ednum value per date (ednum value being MAX) Here is my attempt, it runs but is not giving the MAX(ednum) value but including additional rows of the same date.

MS SQL 2008

```
SELECT TP2.ednum, TP2.BackgroundID, TP2.Patient_No, TP2.Last_Name, TP2.Visit_Name, 
TP2.SessionDT
FROM  dbo.TypePatient AS TP1 INNER JOIN
      (SELECT ednum, BackgroundID, CONVERT(varchar,  DATE_, 101) AS SessionDT, Patient_No, Last_Name, Visit_Name
              FROM          dbo.TypePatient
              WHERE      (Visit_Name = 'Progress Note')) AS TP2  ON TP1.BackgroundID = TP2.BackgroundID AND TP1.ednum =
              (SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT MAX(ednum) AS ednum
              FROM          dbo.TypePatient
              WHERE      (BackgroundID = 3304) AND (TP2.SessionDT
BETWEEN '09/20/2015' AND '09/26/2015') AND (Visit_Name = 'Progress Note')
ORDER BY TP2.SessionDT)
GROUP BY TP2.SessionDT, TP2.ednum, TP2.BackgroundID, TP2.Patient_No, TP2.Last_Name, TP2.Visit_Name, TP2.ednum
```

MS SQL 2008

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH X AS 
(
    SELECT ednum
         , BackgroundID
         , Patient_No
         , Last_Name
         , Visit_Name
         , SessionDT
         , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Patient_No ORDER BY ednum DESC) rn 
    FROM  dbo.TypePatient 
    WHERE Visit_Name = 'Progress Note'
     AND SessionDT BETWEEN '20150920' AND '20150926'
)
SELECT * FROM X 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: No doubt this is much simpler. I was working with Over Partition while waiting for a possible answer. However I need all days but the MAX enum for each day. Commenting out rn=1 it gave me the same results I was getting.

ednum BID         PaientID Lname SessionDT                        rn
258879 3304 118955X Smith 2015-09-24 11:07:58.000 1
258863 3304 118955X Smith 2015-09-24 10:24:59.000 2
258556 3304 118955X Smith 2015-09-23 13:02:20.000 3